# transport and message level security in enterprise application

Tags: security, esb, transport-security

i'm Going to design enterprise application which expose web services to out side. i'm going to ESB and i read that we can set security in ESB too.

According to my finding we need to consider about transport level security and message level security.

so i found for transport layer we can use 2 way SSL or 1 way SSL.

if i'm going to use ESB with 2 way ssl, Do i need to use message level security?
can ESB handle message level security?

i read following : [Is Transport Level Security Necessary When Using Message Level Security in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829521/is-transport-level-security-necessary-when-using-message-level-security-in-wcf)

[Transport-level vs message-level security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270883/transport-level-vs-message-level-security)

but couldn't find solution

thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wso2 ESB supports message level(soap) security.For more information refer the [doc](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Security+for+Web+Services)