# Need to use SSL certificate in asynchronous WCF communication

Tags: wcf, ssl-certificate, wcf-binding

I have two servers M1, M2 at different locations

The requirement is
M1 just triggers a function at M2 (say GetData) and returns.
After that function (GetData) at M2 executes, it will send the response to M1, say a text file.

Need to implement SSL certificates in this scenario so that M2 should know M1 is authorized to call GetData function and when M2 starts sending data, it make sure M1 is the only one who requested the data and will deliver the file to M1 only not any body else.

I know WCF but I never used SSL Certificates. Also, if M2 is a different source at all(say an API from a vendor), then how I should give certificate to M2.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When faced with similar requirements and environment, we typically implement one of two solutions:

1. SSL with Mutual Certificate Authentication
   One option is to use standard SSL transport layer security with added mutual client and server certificate authentication.  The SSL Mutual Authentication solution should meet most direct communication security requirements.  The following link provides a good overview:
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication  .
   Note:  In the event that your data path “hops” through intermediaries, however, you may want to consider the a Message-Level Security solution (option below).
2. Message Security and Mutual Certificate Authentication
   When using message security, the user credentials and claims are encapsulated in every message using the WS-Security specification to secure messages. This option ensures that message data is secure from originator to the intended recipient, even through intermediates.
   The following links provides a good overview of Message Security with Mutual Certificates.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102.aspx

The following links provide good information regarding the decision to use Transport-level and/or message-level security:
[Transport-level vs message-level security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270883/transport-level-vs-message-level-security)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the information. One of the main concern is how I will hand over the certificate to M2. Is it like I need to physically go and give it to M2 or via mail or something. Secondly, do I need to purchase the certificate and then I need to install one copy of that  in M1 and other copy in M2.

Comment: You will most likely need to setup some type of PKI (maybe just a simple or manual process if the number of exchange partners is small).  The following links provide some added info:   
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23903/how-to-distribute-client-certificates-without-exposing-private-key